# Do we have $\det=e^1\wedge\cdots\wedge e^n$?

Tags: determinant

If we think of the determinant as a multilinear map from the set of $n$-column vectors to $\mathbb{R}$,
$$\det:\mathbb{R}^n\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R},$$
am I right in saying that
$$\det=e^1\wedge\cdots\wedge e^n,$$
where $\{e^i\}$ is the basis dual to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\wedge$ is the [wedge product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra)?

I think we can prove it by just expanding both sides, using Leibniz formula for the determinant and the definition
$$\omega\wedge\eta=\frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}\rm{Alt}(\omega\otimes\eta)$$
for the wedge product of $\omega\in\Lambda^k$, $\eta\in\Lambda^l$.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. Alternatively you can check that $\det$ and $e^1 \wedge \dots \wedge e^n$ agree on a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes \dots \otimes \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Basis_and_dimension) that if $\dim(E) = n$ then $\dim(\Lambda^n(E))$ = 1.

Therefore $\det$ and $e^1 \wedge \dots \wedge e^n$ are colinear. Since they agree (and do non cancel) on the stardard basis of $\Bbb R^n$, they are actually equal.